# How to vertically centre an item

Tags: html, css

I would like to vertically center the word 'Benefits' located in the paragraph tag. As you can see, i have tried doing this with an inline style using verticall-align: middle but no impact is taking place.

```
<ul class="list-inline benefits-hexagon02" style="text-align: center;">
    <li class="benefit-analysis">
        <span class="opp-input topp-cycle cycle-default benefit-buttons icon-benefits00" data-action="class" data-cycle="icon-benefits00,icon-benefits01,icon-benefits02,icon-benefits03,icon-benefits04,icon-benefits05" data-n="<?php echo $BenefitAccuracy; ?>" data-col="pBenefitAccuracy"  aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <p class="waste-label">Accuracy &amp; Precision</p>
    </li>
    <li class="benefit-analysis">
            <p style="text-align: CENTER;"><center>Benefits</center></p>
    </li>
    <li class="benefit-analysis">
        <span class="opp-input topp-cycle cycle-default benefit-buttons icon-benefits00" data-action="class" data-cycle="icon-benefits00,icon-benefits01,icon-benefits02,icon-benefits03,icon-benefits04,icon-benefits05" data-n="<?php echo $BenefitRiskReduction; ?>" data-col="pBenefitRiskReduction"  aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <p class="waste-label">Risk Reduction</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The center element should no longer be used, use `text-align:CENTER;` instead.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and obsolete. `<p>` cannot contain the `<center>` element and the `<center>` element is obsolete.

Comment: You have edited your code to use `text-align`, but your question mentions `vertical-align`. Did `text-align` solve your problem, or do you have the same problem with `text-align`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the `<li>` with the word 'Benefits' inside, to be displayed vertically aligned to the page height, you can use the `transform` CSS3 rule.

Here is an example using your code.

```css
.benefits{
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline benefits-hexagon02" style="text-align: center;">
    <li class="benefit-analysis">
        <span class="opp-input topp-cycle cycle-default benefit-buttons icon-benefits00" data-action="class" data-cycle="icon-benefits00,icon-benefits01,icon-benefits02,icon-benefits03,icon-benefits04,icon-benefits05" data-n="<?php echo $BenefitAccuracy; ?>" data-col="pBenefitAccuracy"  aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <p class="waste-label">Accuracy &amp; Precision</p>
    </li>
    <li class="benefit-analysis benefits">
            <p>Benefits</p>
    </li>
    <li class="benefit-analysis">
        <span class="opp-input topp-cycle cycle-default benefit-buttons icon-benefits00" data-action="class" data-cycle="icon-benefits00,icon-benefits01,icon-benefits02,icon-benefits03,icon-benefits04,icon-benefits05" data-n="<?php echo $BenefitRiskReduction; ?>" data-col="pBenefitRiskReduction"  aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <p class="waste-label">Risk Reduction</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

I removed the `<center>` and `vertical-align` attributes from the HTML code and replaced them with corresponding CSS rules

I added `.benefits` class to the 'Benefits' `<li>` in order to select and apply the css rules specifically to it

Comment: This is on the right track however now I need to control the width of this element to ensure there is a fixed space between the first and third list item. I am not sure the best way to do this.

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua what width do you need to apply it? 100% of the window width like the other two items?

Comment: It would be nice if it was 1/3 the size as well as the other 2 elements

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua Ok, in that case you need to add a `width:33.3%`to the `.benefits` class. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

if `<li class="benefit-analysis">` has fixed height,
then you can add `line-height` to `span` and `p` tags